# session returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session-variables

Im using a session variable to pass the user ID from the Index to the Create in the HomeController.  ATM the user can use a drop down to select their name from the list of users and click *View* to list the holidays they have previously booked.  From there the user can click *create* which will bring the user to a page which enables them to create a new holiday.  From here they have to select their name again from the drop down list.

I want to store the users ID from the previous drop down so it will update automatically if they try to create another holiday (to replace the second drop down)

Im using a session variable to do this, iv put

```
Session["userameID"] = currentID;
```

in my view. Iv break pointed it just after and if I hold my mouse over `currentID` it displays the correct ID of the user.

So iv tried to pass this down to the create method using

```
string xx = (string)Session["usernameID"];
```

However, string 'xx' is returning NULL (tested with breakpoint)

I then placed the entire session in the view

```
Session["userameID"] = HolidayDate;

string xx = (string)Session["usernameID"];
```

and  string `xx` is still returning `null`.

Is it not meant to return the userID???

Thanks for any replys

Comment: kicking in an open door here, but you've got both "usernameID" ànd "userameID"

Comment: is current id a string? I see that you are casting it as a string when reading, but can it be casted?

Comment: @Wimbo opps...bit tired this morning thanks for that, iv edited my Q to a new error please look. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two posible causes of your problem:

1. You are not using the same name for the session variable when you assign it and retrive it (userameID -> usernameID)
2. The type you assign is not a string, when you retrieve the value it can not be casted (assumed you solved issue 1)

Comment: opps only seeing the mistake now sorry, Iv got a new error if you look at my original Q I have edited it thanks

Comment: @John Welcom on SO, you should open a new question and mark the awnser on this question as valid.